# Update a table from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, insert-update

I am using postgres and I have the following two tables. I would like to update the distinct_network_point table with the altitude value taken from the altitude_of_point table joining them on the id value.

The following is the distinct_network_point table:

[image]

The following is the altitude_of_point table:

[image]

How it shall be the structure of the sql query to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it helps:

```
UPDATE distinct_network_point 
SET altitude = altitude_of_point.altitude 
FROM  altitude_of_point 
    WHERE distinct_network_point.id= altitude_of_point.id
```

Comment: The following error poped up:  table name "distinct_network_point" specified more than once

Comment: You don't need to include the table to be updated in the FROM clause. In fact that will create a cartesian join which you definitely do not want. Read the manual - it explicitely covers that.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE distinct_network_point 
SET altitude = altitude_of_point.altitude 
FROM distinct_network_point,  altitude_of_point 
    WHERE distinct_network_point.id= altitude_of_point.id
```